# Interpolate contents of one dataset based on another dataset and merge in R - uneven values

Tags: r, database, merge, interpolation, intervals

I have two datasets (A for the age dataset and TE for the concentration dataset) and I'm aiming to plot concentration ~ Age but I'm stuck on how to merge and expand the Age data to fit the much larger database containing concentrations. These are examples of my two datasets:

1. (A) Distance in this case is in multiples of 25 micrometers and is distance along the slide. The total distance along each slide differs between slides depending on the side of the item on each slide. Age is cumulative age along each slide (so everything is nested within slide).

| Slide | Age | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 25 |
| 1 | 14 | 50 |
| 1 | 22 | 75 |
| 1 | 28 | 100 |
| 2 | 8 | 25 |
| 2 | 15 | 50 |

2. (TE) Distance is continuous and is distance along the slide but more fine scale and distance between one data point to the next is not consistent.

| Slide | Concentration | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7800 | 0.57 |
| 1 | 7895 | 0.61 |
| 1 | 6547 | 1.22 |
| 1 | 6589 | 1.73 |
| 1 | 6887 | 4.89 |
| 1 | 6342 | 5.50 |
| 2 | 8560 | 35.50 |
| 2 | 8657 | 36.11 |
| 2 | 8500 | 38.43 |
| 2 | 8352 | 39.17 |
| 2 | 8334 | 41.01 |
| 2 | 7456 | 42.84 |
| 2 | 8912 | 56.92 |

I need a way to merge the two so I can do:
ggplot(TE, aes(x = Age, y = Concentration, group = Slide))+
geom(line)

...by expanding the age data to fit to the continuous distance scale in the TE dataset by interpolating age for each distance in the TE database. Something like this:

| Slide | Concentration | Distance | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7800 | 0.57 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 7895 | 0.61 | 0.4 |
| 1 | 6547 | 1.22 | 0.8 |
| 1 | 6589 | 1.73 | 1.2 |
| 1 | 6887 | 4.89 | 4.3 |
| 1 | 6342 | 5.50 | 5.5 |
| 2 | 8560 | 35.50 | 7.3 |
| 2 | 8657 | 36.11 | 7.4 |
| 2 | 8500 | 38.43 | 7.6 |
| 2 | 8352 | 39.17 | 7.7 |
| 2 | 8334 | 41.01 | 7.8 |
| 2 | 7456 | 42.84 | 7.9 |
| 2 | 8912 | 56.92 | 8.4 |

Any ideas?

p.s. Sorry if this isn't clear I can update as necessary if it's not reproducible enough

Comment: What do you want your merged data set to look like?  Do you want to interpolate ages in table A to match distances in table TE, or group concentrations in table TE by the distances in table A?  Show an example.

Comment: Yes, I need to interpolate the ages in table A to match the distances in table TE, so I need all the data from the TE database (which is like 260,000 entries)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data for slide 1 in Table A, it appears that there is a linear relationship between age and distance. Rather than initially joining the two tables while simultaneously interpolating distances in Table A based on age, instead you could: 1) `split()` Table A by slide; B) use `lm()` to obtain a linear model of age on distance for each slide; and C) use `predict()` with each linear model and the distance data from Table TE.  This will give you a the linearly interpolated ages for each concentration in Table TE.  The interpolated age and concentration data can then be combined for plotting.

Comment: No there isn't a linear relationship between age and distance, ages vary between 4 and 10 every 25um in distance which makes things more complicated!

Comment: Then it sounds as though you will need to do non-linear interpolation, and finding the right model(s) for the relationship between age and distance is the core of your problem.  Maybe you have a theoretical model to use.  If not, you might use `smooth.spline()` and `predict.smooth.spline()` instead of `lm()` and `predict()`.